# How to repair leak between P-trap arm and drain pipe

Tags: leak, drain, p-trap, abs

I recently replaced my bathroom faucet including the water supply lines and I now have a slow leak from the drain pipe/P-trap connection. I'm thinking I must have accidentally bumped the P-trap or drain pipe when I was under the sink replacing the faucet. The leak is coming from between a 1 1/2" to 1 1/4" reducer and black ABS 1 1/2" pipe (see photos).

Question 1): To repair, do I simply need to replace the 1 1/2" to 1 1/4" ABS to P-trap reducer? If so, will this [product](https://www.lowes.com/pd/NIBCO-1-1-2-in-dia-ABS-Trap-Adapter-Fitting/3436934?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-plb-_-google-_-lia-_-142-_-indoordrainage-_-3436934-_-0&placeholder=null&gclid=Cj0KCQiAnb79BRDgARIsAOVbhRqlrEoS7M9cL50GJuL3yFQpNv5k8MVNxdEZ4oGCB7oknlZKBkr-IJgaAhzMEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) work?

Question 2): As I've never cemented ABS pipe before, my understanding is that I use ABS cement to weld the two pieces of pipe together. If so, will this [product](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Oatey-4-oz-Medium-Black-ABS-Pipe-Cement-309993/100136815) work?

Thank you very much!

[image: drain pipe from above]

[image: drain pipe from below]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that reducer is cemented on to a 22 1/2 degree sweep and separating them will really a job. You best bet would be to remove both those pieces because you don't know exactly which piece is leaking. Cut that second piece where it comes out of the wall as close to the bent as possible to save as much of the protruding pipe so you can cement a new piece on to it. You might have to chip a little wall away to expose more pipe. then get the piping you'll need to reconnect everything, maybe clean it up a bit. that cement will work fine with the ABS piping.

Comment: Yes, that is a strange cobbled-up fitting. It looks like someone glued a 1 1/2" ABS male adapter to a street 1/16" bend...

Comment: Thanks for the posts! Jack - when you say to cut the second piece where it comes out of the wall, are you suggesting that I cut the pipe that goes into the wall OR the 22 1/2 degree sweep? Just want to make sure I understand what I'm removing. Thanks!

Comment: @EliKern You want to cut the pipe that goes into the wall but cut it right up against the sweep to keep as much of it as possible so you can cement the few fitting on to it...

Comment: Thank you so much @Jack!